# Rows showing up as null in database - asp.net c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to make a form send info to a database. The code for my button is below. It seems to connect to the database, but all the values that are added are null. Am I missing something? I've rechecked the ids for the fields in the form (TextBoxUN,TextBoxEmail..) and they all match.

Thanks.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["apstestConnectionString"].ConnectionString);//string used in sql datasource
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into asptable (username,email,password,country) values (@Uname,@email,@password,@country)";
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname,", TextBoxUN.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email,", TextBoxEmail.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password,",TextBoxPass.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country,",DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.ToString());

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close(); 
            Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");

        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Response.Write("Error:"+ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: why is there a comma after every parameter?

Comment: I gave the first answer can you mark as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "," chars from parameters

Answer (score 1):

Remove commas from the end of parameter names when calling Parameters.AddWithValue and see if it helps. So instead of

```
AddWithValue("@Uname,",...)
```

write

```
AddWithValue("@Uname",...)
```

And the same for other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname,", TextBoxUN.Text);` remove the `,` after the parameter name and write `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", TextBoxUN.Text);` without comma. Do this for all parameters.